# How to check if a water body is near a given coordinate. (very often)

Tags: python, maps, mapbox, openstreetmap, geo

I'm doing a project where I want to identify water bodies on satellite images via machine learning.
I'm still figuring out how to generate my dataset of a satellite image + a water mask of the same area.

The procedure I thought of is:

1. Draw a random coordinate (longitude,latitude) inside of european land using the [country borders of Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-admin-0-countries/) (with Numpy and Geopandas)
2. Check if there is some water body in a specified range around this coordinate using [OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) or [Mapbox Vector Tiles API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/vector-tiles-api/). If not return to 1.
3. Generate a satellite image of this location using the [Mapbox Raster Tiles API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/raster-tiles-api/)
4. Generate a mask of waterbodies of this location using the [Mapbox Static Tiles API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/static-tiles-api/) and a custom made Mapbox Style where only water is shown.

At the moment I am most concerned about step 2. because I don't know where I can easily get the information and don't have problems with a request limit.
I want to make a dataset of around 100000 image pairs and because of the low water to land ratio I expect many more requests for the 2. step.

The Mapbox Vector Tiles API has a limit of 200000 requests per month.([see here](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/#vectortile))
And the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) has a limit of around 10000 requests per day.
I found the [OSM Water Layer](http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Eyamadai/OSM_water/) but I have no idea how to use it and check if there is water in a given area.

Has anyone an idea how I could manage to do step 2.? I am using Python.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way might be to import the OSM data of the specific area to a local postGIS database using [Osm2pgsql](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) or ImpOsm and do your analytics there.